# Makefile: rule not found when I add additional prerequisite

Tags: makefile

The following rule in my makefile works fine:

```
$(BUILD)%.o : %.c
    do something
```

However if I add another prerequisite it doesn't anymore:

```
$(BUILD)%.o : %.c $(HEADER_FILES)
    do something
```

I checked that the value of `HEADER_FILES` is correct: it is a space separated list of the header files of my project, with absolute path. Paths are correct, files do exist.

The error message with the second line is the infamous "No rule to make target build/xxx.o"

I don't understand why no rule is found

Comment: It might be unrelated, but you should be using `%.o` and `%.c` respectively.

Comment: Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes it is a typo. I am not allowed to copy my makefile here

Comment: If it's really long then you need to condense it to a [mre] but with the current exposition we can't reproduce or guess what's wrong.

Comment: basically the question is about the management of prerequisites. When  I add (probably in the wrong way) some prerequisites to a working rule, Make doesn't find this rule anymore. I thought that as long a the first prerequisites is older than the target, the recipe of the rule is executed. but probably missing something

Comment: Why does nobody ever read the MRE link? Nobody asks you to provide your whole makefile. What we want is a small makefile written from scratch that demonstrates the same issue.

Comment: _I checked that the value of HEADER_FILES is correct: it is a space separated list of the header files of my project, with absolute path. Paths are correct, files do exist._ Probably not, else the rule would apply. But we cannot really help more. Did you try to add `$(info DEBUG: $(HEADER_FILES))` and `$(info DEBUG: $(wildcard $(HEADER_FILES)))` somewhere in your Makefile?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I displayed the value of HEADER_FILES but in another way. Thank you for the tip though

Comment: So the reason was that one of the dozens of files in HEADER_FILES did not exist. But the error message was not precise and it is hard to check by hand.

Comment: I am not surprised. The use of `info` I suggested would have helped because it would have printed the list of files on one line and the list of **existing** files on the next. The difference would have been obvious. And the error message could not be more accurate than what it was, unfortunately: make does not know what you are trying to do. When it does not find a rule for a target it does not search for rules that _almost_ apply. Maybe the next version will embed ChatGPT and be able to suggest fixes ;-)

Comment: Note that if you have many files `$(info DEBUG: $(filter-out $(wildcard $(HEADER_FILES)),$(HEADER_FILES)))` would be even better: it prints only non-existent files listed in `$(HEADER_FILES)`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet just by curiosity, wouldn't it be possible for Make to display which one of the prerequisite does not exist / does not have a rule to be built ? Actually in my case  the rule does exist, but one of the prerequisite doesn't and Make does know which one since it tries to build every one

Comment: Well, it would have to do this for all rules, including the default rules (and there are many default rules). People tend to complain about make's verbosity, this would be really verbose. But if you accept a very verbose output you can try `make -d` (debug) that will tell you all rules that make considered, including to build missing prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern rule is a *template* of one possible way to build a target.  There are lots of possible ways to build targets, in general.  For an object file it could be compiled from a C source file, a C++ source file, a Fortran source file, a Rust source file, etc. etc.  In addition to any pattern rules that you define, make has a bunch of built-in rules.  Make will try all pattern rules that match the target, in order, until it finds one that works.

If some prerequisite of a pattern rule doesn't exist that's not an error in itself: it just tells make that it should keep looking for more pattern rules that might match this target.  Only if make goes through ALL its pattern rules and NONE of them match, will you get an error: the error you see, that make can't find a way to build that target.

If make were to print out a list of all the prerequisites that *didn't* exist, for every pattern `%.o` it knows about, that would be a lot of confusing output.

In general it's best to NOT add explicit prerequisites to pattern rules as it leads to the confusing output you see.  Instead, you should add explicit prerequisites, like this:

```
$(OBJECTS): $(HEADER_FILES)
```

where `OBJECTS` contains all the object files you want to build (presumably you already need something like this, as a prerequisite of your library or executable target, although you didn't show that part of the makefile).

Since this is an explicit prerequisite, make knows it MUST have those files and will give you a specific error if it can't find one.